# Postgresql counting hits overlaps

Tags: php, postgresql

I have code wich counting unique hits on links. All counting have max clicks before stop traffic and redirect to another link.

```
...
// $link->max_clicks = 100; (example)

if (!empty($link->max_clicks)) {

        $count_unique_clicks = DB::table('links_clicks')->distinct()->select('ip')->count('ip');

        if ($count_unique_clicks >= $link->max_clicks) {
            return redirect($link->url_backup);
        }

    } ...
```

The problem is when I have big traffic redirect stop at 101 or 102 because 2-3 query run at same times and hits in 'if' overlaps. How to prevent this, I need to be sure to redirect stop only at 100 (in this example)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/thatsus/laravel-redlock Do the trick. Redlock lock/unlock process and prevent overlaps.